# DragLinearLayout library crashing at runtime when implemented with LayoutTransition

Tags: java, android, animation, android-linearlayout

The implementation of the DragLinearLayout library  works fine until I also implement Android's LayoutTransition.

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

And I get runtime errors on these two methods in the DragLinearLayout class : 
1. addView(draggedItem.view, switchPosition);  //called in on drag
2. onDrag(deltaY); // called in the onTouchEvent override method.
```

I stopped it crashing by overriding onTouchEvent() in my implementing activity, and setting the setLayoutTransition parameter to null on the DraggerLinearLayout when the row is touched, then in the DragLinearLayout when onAnimaitonEnd is called, I call a method in my implementing activity and make the setLayoutTransition() parameter not null anymore.

But this causes some lag, and on the row you're dragging when you stop the drag and let it settle, it disappears for a second and then reappears.

Is there anyway to implement the LayoutTransition with this library, or any other recommended techniques for using an animation to add rows, and for animating the incrementally increasing size of the DragLinearLayout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is, it is possible.

To do it, make your own DragLinearLayout by taking the code from the library's and copy and pasting into your own class. Or add the library as an external library. We'll refer to this new class as DragLinearLayout2.

In DragLinearLayout2, add a LayoutTransition object as a member variable:

```
 private LayoutTransition layoutTransition;
```

Then, in the startDrag() method, at the top of the method add this:

```
layoutTransition = getLayoutTransition();
                if (layoutTransition != null) {
            setLayoutTransition(null);
                    }
```

Then, in the onDragStop() method, go into the implemented onAnimationEnd() method and add this at the end :

```
 if (layoutTransition != null && getLayoutTransition() == null) {
                                        setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition);
                                    }
```

Message me if you need me to send you my version of the class.